# Why is my DataFrame not saving to variable q5 in Pandas_python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out why when I save my dataframe 'animals' as a csv to variable q5, it does not work?

Any insight would be appreciated. I am working in python and have checked that my dataframe animals has data in it.

```
# Your code goes here
#print(animals)
q5=animals.to_csv('cows_and_goats.csv', index=False)
# Check your answer
q5.check()
```

Comment: What do you expect `q5` to be? `to_csv` returns `None` in this use.

Answer (score 0):

It's because to_csv is an action that writes to csv but doesn't really returns anything if you specifiy a name.

What you want is:

```
q5=animals.to_csv(index=False)
```

For more information:
[https://www.javatpoint.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-csv#:~:text=The%20Pandas%20to_csv()%20function,returned%20in%20a%20string%20format](https://www.javatpoint.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-csv#:%7E:text=The%20Pandas%20to_csv()%20function,returned%20in%20a%20string%20format).